# Integração StackOverflow e GIST do GitHub

Tags: novo-recurso

Há alguma alguma intenção de permitir o uso do GIST do GitHub dentro do StackOverflow?

Acho muito prático o uso da ferramenta tanto pela possibilidade de versionar os pedaços de códigos, como também pela centralização de códigos.

Comment: Podes dar alguns exemplos de que novas funcionalidades isso daria? Eu uso muito o Gist mas não estou a ver de que maneira o SOpt iria benefeciar de uma integração.

Comment: @Sergio, ao meu ver isso seria benéfico para o usuário que apresenta o código funcional em um ou mais arquivos, ele poderá manter uma versão do código. Sendo um código maior, este poderá inclusive ser baixado via GIT para a máquina de quem deseja ajudar usando a opção de clonagem, podendo assim replicar rapidamente o código para fazer um teste sem ter que usar CTRL-V/CTRL-C. O programador terá um local central onde poderá manter seus códigos armazenados,

Comment: Duas notas, o Github não é o unico sistema de repositório que existe (seria melhor vincular ao protocolo GIT e não ao GitHub) e nota2: o Carrers pode ser "integrado".

Comment: Sem dúvida @GuilhermeNascimento, porém percebo que seja o mais utilizado, mas perde para o pastebin em relação ao gist. O meu career já está integrado com o github e bitbucket. Mas já seria um passo interessante termos algo inicial apenas com o gist.

Comment: A entendi, pensei que você queria vincular o perfil, desculpe a viagem. A vantagem do pastebin é que não precisa de conta este é o motivo do por que usam mais.

Comment: Eu até acho que o pastebin tem mais recursos, mas gosto do gist porque ele é integrado ao github, tanto por usar a muitos anos, como por ser GIT.